# converting MS Sql server database to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i have developed one website using asp.net and MS SqlServer. Now i want to change my database to MySQL.
now i need to convert all the tables and stored procedures to MySQL
how to convert MS Sql server database to MySQL?

Comment: One table at a time.  Then one stored procedure at a time.

Comment: but while converting stored procedures am getting syntactical errors.

Comment: I would listen to Gordon if I were you.

Comment: Depending on the versions of MySQL and MSSQL, you'll likely want to look into either using SSIS or SSMA to transfer the table data.

Comment: yeah i converted one by one table and stored procedures but i cant able to convert some stored procedures.